# Excel 2002 (sp3) rewrite URI to an addin

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2002

I have a workbook which has a reference to an Excel addin. The addin lives on a network drive.

So when I add the reference, the path of the reference is something like `\\intranet-server-ABC\Path\to\Addin`.

However, after I saved and reopen the book, in the reference dialog box I can see the path is somehow changed to  `\\server-alias-toABC\Path\to\Addin`.

Both URI are actually equivalent. Following the URIs will lead to the same addin file.

Why would Excel rewrite the URI? What is the rule behind the rewrite?

Comment: As far as I know, Excel is doing what Windows tells it to. Check if the same thing happens with other Microsoft products.

Comment: What other MS products/feature can I try? Just can't think of any app/function that might do this

Comment: What I mean is, I think Windows is converting it, not Excel specifically. Test it with saving an Office document on a network share and see if it rewrites the URI.